# How to open the Synaptic Package Manager in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, synaptic

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 11.10.  How to open the Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and I get this: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another sourceE: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate What should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to install Synaptic first. You can do that by clicking here: [Synaptic](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/synaptic)

or by typing

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

in a terminal. (In order to open the terminal press: CTRL + ALT + T)

After this you just need to hit the Super key (or Windows) and type Synaptic and hit enter (to actually open the package manager).

Comment: In case anybody's wondering, this is necessary because Synaptic is no longer installed in Ubuntu by default, starting with 11.10.

Comment: BTW, lot of programs required for non-cli folks are missing. I was not able to add a user in a group from UI, the screen saver and the power settings are missing. Not all applications were shown in the 'startup-applications', I had to manually tweak /etc/xdg/autostart. Ubuntu was supposed to be for Linux beginers, I think it's getting away from it. FYI, I had been using Ubuntu for more than 5 years and this is the first release I didn't like. There will be more Q likes these :( OMG Ubuntu !!!

Comment: @Praveen It sounds like your upgrade is incomplete, you should post that as a new question.

Comment: @Jorge - I did a complete fresh install and all the problems which I mentioned exist and I did find solutions for the same.