# How come 11.10 doesn't come with some of the applications from 11.04?

Tags: 11.10, installation, raid

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) on a RAID stripe.

In order to install on a RAID I had to use the [Alternate Installation](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/) (ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)

I noticed off-the-bat that some applications that were in 11.04 are no longer in 11.10 like Synaptic Package Manager or Startup Applications (it's there, but shows an empty list...).

How come they are no longer there?

I need to avoid downloading anything extra due to my limited internet connection (satellite). I have 500mb/daily @ 100Mb (6-60KB/s). On top of that, it is throttled from 1:00-20:00! [On top of that...](http://www.xplornet.com/legal/xplornet-traffic-management-policy.aspx) It took two days to retrieve the ISO.

The [MD5](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/MD5SUMS) matches the ISO I downloaded so I think that tells me that [nothing is missing](https://askubuntu.com/q/70046/22554)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You noticed right. Some applications were removed from the CD installation in order to make room for some other apps.

But concider that you wont need Synaptic in 11.10 for normal use since the Ubuntu Software Center was greatly improved and has nearly all functionality Synaptic has (see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter/SynapticSoftwareCenterComparison )

New apps include Deja Dup, a powerful and easy-to-use back-up tool which I consider to me more useful for most users then Synaptic.

Comment: Thanks; but software centre only supports 50% of the features in synaptic. The biggest thing for me was installing programs compiled from source. Especially when I create my own deb files using `checkinstall`. My new re-compiled deb files will no longer open in software centre, the window just stays blank (I will investigate this issue futher and maybe ask another question). I am ready to adapt though and start exploring these new features.

Comment: As mentioned before, i talk about normal users. For people like you (and me), there still is Synaptic, which is not that big that you could not install it. developing ubuntu is a trade-off between usability and meeting the needs of more advanced users.

Answer (score 2):

Some applications have been removed due to **incompatibility with GTK 3**. For example Screen Ruler and TSClient just to mention a few. ([Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ugr-meta/+bug/799068))

The main difference though, until these applications start to support GTK 3, you cannot install them, in contrast to synaptic that is a single `sudo apt-get install synaptic` affair.

Another reason could be **licensing changes**. Like with Oracle Java. (But fortunately this can be resolved.)