# software center won't open, triggers system problem detected message, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-center

Lately software center won't open, when I try some of the fixes such as reinstall, I get this dialog:

```
john@john-Dell-DM051:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
[sudo] password for john: 
john@john-Dell-DM051:~$  97%
john@john-Dell-DM051:~$ software-center
2015-03-19 11:51:44,020 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-03-19 11:51:44,241 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2015-03-19 11:51:46,991 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-03-19 11:51:47,822 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2015-03-19 11:51:50,278 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
john@john-Dell-DM051:~$ ^C
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's up but software centre is often glitchy
Use [Synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70046/how-to-open-the-synaptic-package-manager-in-unity) in the meantime